# how to select coefficient in texreg in an easier way

Tags: r

I am analysing a panel dataset with dummy variable fixed effects.
For example, my model looks like

```
model1 <- lm_robust(y ~ x1 + x2 + factor(x3):factor(x3), clusters = clusters, data = data)
```

While there are a lot of categories of x3 and x4 generating hundreds of dummies in the table which I do not want to show.
Is there an easier way with texreg to keep only the estimates of x1 and x2 in the output table?

As I am using lm_robust for clustering, so stargazer is not the option here.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You should find and nominate a readily accessible example dataset that can be used to illustrate methods. AND you need a library() call to load whatever non-standard package holds `lm_robust`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do this in `texreg`, but here is one option using
the [`modelsummary` package for
`R`](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) (disclaimer: I
am the author).

You can use the `coef_map` argument to select the coefficients to
display. You may also want to look at the `coef_omit` argument.

```r
library(estimatr)
library(modelsummary)

mod <- lm_robust(hp ~ ., data = mtcars)

modelsummary(mod, coef_map = c("cyl", "disp"))
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| cyl | 8.204 |
|  | (10.203) |
| disp | 0.439 |
|  | (0.179) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 |
| R2 | 0.903 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.857 |
| Std.Errors | HC2 |